# Find everything except directories

Tags: find

How to ignore directories during find executing? For example there is the following:

```
.
├── fold
│   └── something
└── something
```

*fold/something* - directory
*./something* - file

I do `find . -name "something"` and I wont to ignore *fold/something* because this is the directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You test for a directory with `-type d`.  You invert the sense of a test with `!`.

Therefore:

```
find . -name something ! -type d
```

This would find everything called `something` in or below the current directory, but it would not report any *directory* called `something`.

If you want to ignore `./fold/something` specifically, use a negated `-path` test:

```
find . -name something ! -path ./fold/something
```

Note that the pathname that you use in the `-path` test should match the full path from the top-level search path (`.`).

If you want to stop `find` from reporting any directory called `something`, and also stop it from even entering those directories, use `-prune`:

```
find . \
    -name something -type d -prune -o \
    -name something -print
```

or, equivalently,

```
find . -name something \( -type d -prune -o -print \)
```

This would first prune any found directory called `something` from the search tree.  If the current path being examined is not a directory called `something`, but something else called `something`, then it is printed.  This would not find anything called `something` under `./fold/something`, regardless of its filetype (since `./fold/something` would have been removed from the search tree).